# Submit data along with File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to post form data (such as textbox, checkbox etc) along with a File Upload . I am using MVC.

Any one give me a solutions?

Comment: What code are you trying at the moment? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your Post Controller will look like this :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult YourController(YourModel model1, HttpPostedFileBase file)
 {
    if (file != null)
        {
            //here file variable will have the file which you have uploaded
        }
 }
```

`HttpPostedFileBase` contains the file which you have posted from View.

and in your view BeginForm() should look like :

```
Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do it with MVC, with strong-typed as suggested above or this way also would work

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateUpdate(FormCollection _formValues, YourModel _extraItem)
        {
           HttpPostedFileBase files = HttpContext.Request.Files;

           //do whatever u wish with ure files here
        }
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

i use XMLHttpRequest to resolve this solution. Thanks everyone so much :D